# How to train SVM classifier multiple times using python?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

Is it possible to train SVM classifier multiple times? So I will not manually change the parameters whenever I will run it again

This is the code for training the model I have so far:

```
    dictionary = make_Dictionary(TRAIN_DIR)

    print("reading and processing emails from file.")

    features_matrix, labels = extract_features(TRAIN_DIR, dictionary)
    test_feature_matrix, test_labels = extract_features(TEST_DIR, dictionary)

    model = svm.SVC(kernel="poly", degree= 4, C = 0.9)



    print("Training Model")

    #train model
    model.fit(features_matrix, labels)

    predicted_labels = model.predict(test_feature_matrix)

    print("FINISHED classifying. accuracy score : ")

    print (accuracy_score(test_labels, predicted_labels))
```

Comment: Do you want to do [`sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html)?

Comment: hun?  `for` loops?

Comment: @Julien yes, i know i should use for loops to iterate it but i'm confused on how to do so. should i create a list?

Comment: @Chris i was instructed to only use sklearn.svm.SVC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice would to create lists of the the parameters you wish to test upon, and then run them through a for loop. Say you want to test everything on four different sets of parameters (excuse if the values are not as you wish, they can be changed, just created to illustrate the point):

```
degreeArr = [3,4,5,6]
CArr = [0.7,0.8,0.9,1]
```

I am assuming those are the only two parameters you wish to mess around with. Then you can write your for loop:

```
for x in range(len(degreeArr)): #This assumes degreeArr and CArr are the same length
  model = svm.SVC(kernel='poly', degree=degreeArr[x], C=CArr[x])

  print("Training Model")

  #train model
  model.fit(features_matrix, labels)

  predicted_labels = model.predict(test_feature_matrix)

  print("FINISHED classifying. accuracy score : ")

  print (accuracy_score(test_labels, predicted_labels))
```

Note that the only change being made is to the model, so the rest of your code stays the same (but must be included within the for loop). Another note is that the CArr and degreeArr will only be tested with their matching indexes in the array because it is not being done with a double for loop. If you wish to test all possible combinations within those two arrays, simply just add another for loop and make one small adjustment to your model:

```
for x in range(len(degreeArr)):
  for i in range(len(CArr)):
    model = svm.SVC(kernel='poly', degree=degreeArr[x], C=CArr[i])
```

The rest of your code will the stay the same, just like if done through a single for loop.

Let me know if this helps!